# How do I stop Python script from referring to deleted OAuth 2.0 Client ID?

Tags: python, jupyter, google-api-python-client, gspread, pygsheets

Even though I've already generated a new OAuth 2.0 Client ID and client_secret json file, my script keeps on displaying this result:

> RefreshError: ('deleted_client: The OAuth client was deleted.', {'error': 'deleted_client', 'error_description': 'The OAuth client was deleted.'})

Comment: Are you sure the path to your `client_secrets.json` is correct?

Comment: Hi Shuo, yes, the script is referring to the new client_secrets.json already. The old client_secrects.json file is already deleted.